# Нужна ли запятая перед какой

Tags: пунктуация

В частности, занимаемся приемом и продажей товаров в магазинах и в счетах указывали не только, какой товар рекламируется, но и в каком магазине размещается товар.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*В частности, занимались приемом и продажей товаров в магазинах и в счетах указывали **не только** какой товар рекламируется, **но и** в каком магазине размещается товар.
Запятая перед «какой» не нужна.*

Двойной союз НЕ ТОЛЬКО…НО И соединяет однородные придаточные (союзные слова КАКОЙ, В КАКОМ).

У Розенталя на эту тему можно найти такое правило:

4. Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится:

1. если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит отрицательная частица НЕ: *Он знает **не только** где водится дичь, **но и** какие её разновидности там обитают;*
   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

Вариант редактирования (для лучшего понимания структуры предложения): *В частности, занимались приемом и продажей товаров в магазинах, **причем** в счетах указывали не только какой товар рекламируется, но и в каком магазине размещается товар.*